# Make form field required based on another field value in angular 5

Tags: forms, angular5

I have the following form. I want to make the graph type compulsory. However the X and Y axes values should be made compulsory only if the graph is bar or line graph and not pie or doughnut graph. According to my code, X and Y axes values are compulsory throughout. Please help.

html

```
    <form [formGroup]="clientForm" (ngSubmit)="clientForm.valid && changeGraph()" #formLogin="ngForm">

              <div class="form-group">
            <label> Graph Type </label>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="type">
              <option disabled [ngValue]="null"> Select Option </option>
              <option *ngFor='let t of types' [ngValue]="t"> {{t}} </option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-err" *ngIf="(clientForm.controls['type'].hasError('required') && clientForm.controls['type'].touched) || (clientForm.controls['type'].hasError('required') && formLogin.submitted)"> Please enter Graph Type </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
            <label> X-Axis </label>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="xAxis">
              <option disabled [ngValue]="null"> Select Option </option>
              <option *ngFor='let dim of dimensions?.data' [ngValue]="dim"> {{dim}} </option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-err" *ngIf="(clientForm.controls['xAxis'].hasError('required') && clientForm.controls['xAxis'].touched) || (clientForm.controls['xAxis'].hasError('required') && formLogin.submitted)"> Please enter Dimension </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
            <label> Y-Axis </label>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="yAxis">
              <option disabled [ngValue]="null"> Select Option </option>
              <option *ngFor='let dim of dimensions?.data' [ngValue]="dim"> {{dim}} </option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-err" *ngIf="(clientForm.controls['yAxis'].hasError('required') && clientForm.controls['yAxis'].touched) || (clientForm.controls['yAxis'].hasError('required') && formLogin.submitted)"> Please enter Measure </div>
              </div>

              <button class="client-side-window-btn" type="submit">
            Save
              </button>

     </form>
```

ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-client',
      templateUrl: './client.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./client.component.css']
    })
    export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

      //Form params
      clientForm: FormGroup;
      type:FormControl;
      xAxis:FormControl;
      yAxis:FormControl;


      //dropdown arrays
      public dimensions:string[]= ['Plant','Year','Month'];

      public types: string[]= ['bar','line','pie','doughnut'];

        constructor(
          private form:FormBuilder,
          private forms:FormsModule) {
     }

        ngOnInit() {
          this.clientForm = this.form.group({
           'type': [null, Validators.required],
           'xAxis': [null, Validators.required],
           'yAxis': [null, Validators.required],
         });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `(change)="callback()"` you can trigger a function.
Then with `formControl.setValidators()` you can set validators.

**EDIT**

you'll also need `formControl.updateValueAndValidity()` to actually trigger validations.

[StackBlits Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/update-validators)

Please note that you can't read current validators (actually it's possibile but kinda tricky), but only overwrite them.

**html**

```
            <select (change)="updateAxisFields()" class="form-control" formControlName="type">
              <option disabled [ngValue]="null"> Select Option </option>
              <option *ngFor='let t of types' [ngValue]="t"> {{t}} </option>
            </select>
```

**ts**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-client',
      templateUrl: './client.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./client.component.css']
    })
    export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

      //Form params
      optional: string[] = ['pie', 'doughnut'];
      clientForm: FormGroup;
      type:FormControl;
      xAxis:FormControl;
      yAxis:FormControl;


      //dropdown arrays
      public dimensions:string[]= ['Plant','Year','Month'];

      public types: string[]= ['bar','line','pie','doughnut'];

        constructor(
          private form:FormBuilder,
          private forms:FormsModule) {
     }

        ngOnInit() {
          this.clientForm = this.form.group({
           'type': [null, Validators.required],
           'xAxis': [null, Validators.required],
           'yAxis': [null, Validators.required],
         });
      }

   updateAxisFields(): void {
        console.info("updateAxis");
        const type = this.clientForm.controls.type.value;

        const xAxis = this.clientForm.controls.xAxis;
        const yAxis = this.clientForm.controls.yAxis;
        const newValidators = [];
        this.axisRequired = this.optional.indexOf(type) > -1
        if (this.axisRequired) {
          newValidators.push(Validators.required);
        }
        xAxis.setValidators(newValidators);
        xAxis.updateValueAndValidity();
        yAxis.setValidators(newValidators);
        yAxis.updateValueAndValidity();
     }
}
```

Comment: Its not working. On selecting bar and clicking submit without choosing axes, error is shown. The same thing is also shown for pie and doughnut.

Comment: You wanna bet? I'm creating a stackblitz.

Comment: Anyway I just noticed you're mixing **template driven** with **data driven** forms. Either you use `ngForm` or you use `formGroup`. That's why it doesn't work

Comment: wait. I'm working on stackblitz. I'll link it in the answer as soon as I'm done.

Comment: I just changed the values in the optional array to bar and line. Now it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You wrote "should be made compulsory only if the graph is bar or line graph and not pie or doughnut", so you meant the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

As to me - the simplest way is to operate "disabled" state like this:

```
this.batchForm.controls.isManual.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
  if (Boolean(value) === true) {
    this.batchForm.get('hangfireRecurringJob').disable();
  }
  else {
    this.batchForm.get('hangfireRecurringJob').enable();
  }
});
```